# Select function not working tkinter text

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I have a find function which works except when it comes to the selection part. It selects from the phrase it found to the end. How do I get it to only select what i want it to?

```
def find_helper(text,win=None):
    if win: win.destroy()
    global box
    lengthvar=IntVar()
    where=box.search(text,1.0,count=lengthvar)
    box.tag_add(SEL, float(where), float(where)+lengthvar.get())
    return 'break'
def find(a=None):
    global box
    ask=Tk()
    what=Entry(ask)
    confirm=Button(ask,text='Ok',command=lambda:find_helper(what.get(),ask))
    what.pack()
    confirm.pack()
    ask.mainloop()
```

This is my output:

> This is so*me text*

(The part in italics is the selected part - from 'm' to the last 't')

...but the thing I searched for was actually 'me'.
WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?!
(tried on windows 7 python 3.4)

Comment: what is `box.search`

Comment: _box_ is my [tkinter text](http://effbot.org/tkinter-book/text.htm) widget, and search is it's _find_ method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
box.tag_add(SEL, float(where), float(where)+lengthvar.get())
```

Specifically, the problem is with the use of `float`.

Text indexes are *not* floating point numbers, and converting the index to a float is incorrect and will yield unexpected results. Indexes must be strings of the form "line.character".

This makes a difference because`"1.10"` in string format will be converted to `1.1` as a float, and those two numbers represent different places in the text widget.

The right way to highlight what is found would be something like this:

```
box.tag_add(SEL, where, "%s + %dc" % (where, lengthvar.get()))
```

The second index will end up looking something like `"1.10 + 7c"` which tkinter will interepret as "line 1, character 10, plus 7 more characters".